# Iterating through database with nested lists

Tags: python, list, recursion, nested-lists

I'm trying to iterate through nested lists and match it to a pattern, then create a list of matches. However my matching function can only go through the outer most list so far. How could expand it (the matching function) so it would also read all of the nested lists in the database. Here is the code:

```
database = [[['author', ['karl', 'jacksson']], ['title', ['jumping', 
  'high']], ['year', 2010]], [['author', ['keith', 'night']], 
  ['title', ['chasing', 'shadows', 'in', 'the', 'dark']], 
  ['year', 2012]]]

pattern = ['--', ['titel', ['&', '&']], '--']
```

('--' menas it can match 0 or more elements, '&' means it may only match one element)

```
def searching(pattern, database):
    '''
    Go through the database and see if anything matches the pattern 
    then create a list of all matched patterns
    '''
    return [i for i in database if matching(i, pattern)]

def matching(sequence, the_pattern):
    """
    Returns if a given sequence matches the given pattern
    """
    if not the_pattern:
        return not sequence
    elif the_pattern[0] == '--':
        if matching(sequence, the_pattern[1:]):
            return True
        elif not sequence:
            return False
        else:
            return matching(sequence[1:], the_pattern)
    elif not sequence:
        return False
    elif the_pattern[0] == '&':
        return matching(sequence[1:], the_pattern[1:])
    elif sequence[0] == pattern[0]:
        return matching(sequence[1:], the_pattern[1:])
    else:
        return False
```

Here is an example:

INPUT

```
searching(['--', ['titel', ['&', '&']], '--'], database)
```

OUTPUT

```
[[['author', ['karl', 'jacksson']], ['title', ['jumping', 'high']], 
['year', 2010]]]
```

Comment: If I follow your searching logic correctly, in your example, you're looking for any row with a title of length two?

Comment: Yes that is correct! @blacksite

Comment: Okay. It doesn't seem recursion is necessary in your case. Check out my answer below and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I think you may be interested in the [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/) library. This seems like it may do what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions/approaches (in-progress... will update with additional pieces):

```
database = [
    [
        ['author', ['karl', 'jacksson']],
        ['title', ['jumping', 'high']],
        ['year', 2010]
    ],
    [
        ['author', ['keith', 'night']],
        ['title', ['chasing', 'shadows', 'in', 'the', 'dark']],
        ['year', 2012]
    ]
]

# The pattern you specify, with a slight spelling correction:
pattern = ['--', ['title', ['&', '&']], '--']

# It seems you're jut interested in rows where `title` is of length two
# so why not query the "database" like so?
def search(pattern, database):
    for record in database:
        # Assumes that your pattern is defined for all keys in each record
        # i.e. if there are three "columns" in all records, then the pattern
        # if of length three, as well
        record_with_pattern = zip(record, pattern)
        for (key, record_data), pattern_data in record_with_pattern:
            # Might be simpler to just use `None` instead of '--'
            if pattern_data != '--':
                if len(pattern_data) == len(record_data):
                    print('Match: {}'.format(str(record)))

search(pattern, database)
# Match: [['author', ['karl', 'jacksson']], ['title', ['jumping', 'high']], ['year', 2010]]
```

Comment: This works good for the specific example I gave, however it won't work for other cases. For example if the pattern was: ['--', ['year', 2095], '--'], then it should return an empty list (because nothing matches with the year 2095) but this solution will still return the same match as earlier. I think the searching function works fine but there is something that has to be done to the matching function for it to be able to go through multiple list.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of different pattern-searching cases you're trying to account for. Is this a homework assignment? If not, an actual database will more fully-fledged querying capabilities might be worthwhile.